# Found unknown categories when doing regression with categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, rfe

Im doing linear regression with ScikitLearn and Python.
My data have categorical values, so i used encoding.

```
df = df[['Lokacija','Kvadratura', 'Stanje', 'Kategorija',
         'Grejanje', 'Ukupno spratova','Sprat','Ukupna cena']]

encoder = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['Lokacija', 'Stanje', 'Grejanje']),
    ('scale', StandardScaler(), ['Kvadratura','Kategorija', 'Ukupno spratova', 'Sprat'])],
     remainder='passthrough')

x = df.iloc[:,:-1]
x = encoder.fit_transform(x)
y = df.iloc[:,-1]
```

I wanted to find the optimal number of features, so I used `RFE`

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

for i in range(1,5):
    final_rfe = RFE(LinearRegression(), i)
    model = final_rfe.fit(x_train, y_train)

#ERROR IN LINE BELOW!

    input_par = encoder.transform(pd.DataFrame([{
                                                "Lokacija": 'Vracar', 
                                                'Kvadratura': 56,
                                                'Stanje': 'Novogradnja',
                                                'Grejanje': 'Centralno grejanje',
                                                'Ukupno spratova': 6,
                                                'Sprat': 3}]))

    my_prediction = model.prediction(input_par)
    reg_score = model.score(x_test, y_test)
    print(my_prediction[0], reg_score)
```

But when I done this, I got this error:

```
ValueError: Found unknown categories ['Vracar'] in column 0 during transform
```

What am I doing wrong?
I know that problem is in transformation, but I do not know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Does your data in `x` contains a row that `Lokacija` has `Vracar` value? If the encoder doesn't see this in `fit_transform` it can't transform it later. You can check with `df[df["Lokacija"] == "Vracar"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two possible solutions:

- Do **stratify** during train/test splitting: `x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, stratify=df[['Lokacija', 'Stanje', 'Grejanje']], random_state=42)`
- Change the way how to handle an **unknown categorical feature**: `('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), ['Lokacija', 'Stanje', 'Grejanje'])`

Comment: So what does `stratify` mean and `handle_unknown`?

Comment: For `stratify` - data is split in a stratified fashion, using this as the class labels. For instance, your dataset will be split in such way, that `x_train` and `x_test` will contain all possible values for the `'Lokacija', 'Stanje', 'Grejanje'`.                       
For `handle_unknown` - when an unknown category is encountered during transform, the resulting one-hot encoded columns for this feature will be all zeros. In the inverse transform, an unknown category will be denoted as None.